# Swift: How to set round UIBezierPath position

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibezierpath

I just created a round line with UIBezierPath using this code: `let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: timerLabel.layer.position, radius: frame.size.width / 2 - 80, startAngle: -0.5 * CGFloat.pi, endAngle: 1.5 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)`
And I want my circle to have the position of my TimerLabel. But as you can see in the image, my circle just doesn't want to be placed in the middle of my timer label.
[image: Look:]
I have already tried to set the arcCenter parameter to timerlabel.center, CGPoit (x: timerlabel.x, y: timerlabel.y) and so on. But the circle is still not centered. Can someone help me? Warm greetings

Comment: Could you set the background color of the label? Its frame might no be what you think it is. Also, when do you call your drawing? If you use Autolayout, the frame you have when drawing might not be the final ones.

Comment: You need to provide more code. Post the whole method that builds and installs your circle path, as well as your view controller lifecycle methods to handle viewDidAppear, layout changes, etc. As Larme points out, views are often created with frames that get changed before they are displayed (and can change again for things like device rotation, or the user opening a second app using iPad multitasking.) You should write your code to detect layout changes and regenerate your paths.

Comment: Do you want a label, centered in a circle? Or, are you planning on using that circle as a type of "progress indicator" (that is, maybe it's only a half-circle if the time is 0:30, for example)?